# What branches should SNAPSHOT versions be present in?

Tags: git-flow

According to Gitflow, where should POMs with `-SNAPSHOT` suffixes be placed? From what I've understood, develop should *always* contain a SNAPSHOT version so that we can build the latest SNAPSHOT from each feature that is pushed to that branch.

When we then want to release, we create a release branch from develop. Should this release branch have the SNAPSHOT suffix or not? Should the SNAPSHOT suffix be present in master when we merge the release branch?

If it should be present, how do we effectively tell CI that we want a release if no branch contains a version number without SNAPSHOT?

I currently have the *latest release* in master, i.e. no suffix. My develop branch is building snapshots when new features are merged.

Comment: Snapshot stands vaguely for *"in between releases"* so a release should not be called a SNAPSHOT but rather RELEASE or by increase of the verison number. E.g. from `01.03.04.46-SNAPSHOT` to `02.00.00.00-RELEASE` or just `02.00.00.00`

Comment: This question doesn't really relate directly to programming or to tools. It's more about the software engineering lifecycle. As such, it's better suited to [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Michael when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)